# Connect Flash with SOAP

Tags: flash, soap, https

I want to connect to a SOAP web service in Flash. The SOAP web services is hosted on https and requires username and password. I can't find any documentation or libraries for this action.

Answer (score 2):

`HTTPService` is what you need.

For documentation, visit
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html